# How to show gif image in android?

Tags: android, image, gif

Can any one tell me how to show .gif images in android.I have Google for it, but i found some samples but those are all uncleared.Can anyone give me at least one simple sample for this?

Suggestions please

thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: You can load .gif images using webview.

Comment: Try this link, it might help you out.
http://iamvijayakumar.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-animated-gif-example.html

Comment: Is your question regarding Animated GIFs, or just to display it as a static image? I believe you can use the Android.graphics.Movie class for animated gifs. Otherwise, we'll need more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use each frame of a gif to create an animation using [AnimationDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html).

Answer (score 1):

The link have nice working example [you can check this out.](http://www.anddev.org/resources/file/549) There are lots of tutorial over there on net, by which you can do this. As far as i know android can not play gif without webview, but [this tutorial](http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/) shows how to do it with image view(i haven't tried it).

Comment: i cannot able to view the above url,what you have given

Answer (score 1):

I did it with a `WebView`

```
WebView webView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webView.loadUrl(URL_IMAGE);
```

with `setLoadWithOverviewMode()` and `setUseWideViewPort()` methods will show content fits on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The Glide library supports animated gifs now: https://github.com/bumptech/glide

It is apparently based on this gist: https://gist.github.com/devunwired/4479231